# Apply a Vim macro to multiple lines

Tags: json, vim, macros

I made a simple macro to increment a number in a json object like this:

```
{
    image: 'images/2.jpg',
    thumb: 'images/2-thumb.jpg',
    big: 'images/2.jpg',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    link: 'images/2.jpg'
},
```

with:

```
q, n, shift-v, down-till-end, p, move-to-numbers, c-a, return-to-top, q, 150@n
```

(Sorry if that's not the appropriate syntax to post vim macros here in SE)

And it works, but it makes the increment just until the 9th. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to reach something like this:

```
{
    image: 'images/3.jpg',
    thumb: 'images/3-thumb.jpg',
    big: 'images/3.jpg',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    link: 'images/3.jpg'
},
{
    image: 'images/4.jpg',
    thumb: 'images/4-thumb.jpg',
    big: 'images/4.jpg',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    link: 'images/4.jpg'
},
... until *nth* value
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do? Are you just trying to increment a number on every line of a file? `:%norm ^A` (`^A` is created by ctrl-q ctrl-a)

Comment: I think i misunderstand your question. Could you provide the value of the register 'n' you can see it pressing `<C-R>n` while in insert mode

Comment: I'm trying to "duplicate" a json object but with a "+1" value on the images, like this: foo1.jpg, foo2.jpg, foo3.jpg, foo4.jpg

Comment: @ramonovski, you are supposed to upvote/accept helpful answers to show your appreciation. (But "Thank you." is nice too ;-))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your cursor is on the first opening bracket, here is one way to do it:

```
qn                    " start recording in register n
V%                    " select from here to the closing bracket, linewise
y                     " yank the selection
%                     " jump to the closing bracket
p                     " paste after the current line
:'[,']norm <C-v><C-a> " executing the normal mode command <C-a>(1) on all the lines that we just pasted
q                     " stop recording
```

then do `150@n`.

(1) `<C-v><C-a>` is used to insert a literal `^A`.

Comment: This is nearly identical to what I came up with. But where would we be with out a bit of vim golfing? You can drop the `'[` to shorten it by 2 characters.

Comment: My answer looks like an overblown plagiarized version of your comment. I shouldn't skip comments before rushing to the answer form!

Comment: I am glad you did because your macro was shorter than mine: ``qn8yy`]p:,']norm ^Q^A^M[q``

Comment: Thank you so much, romainl, it works! Can you explain the "'[,']" part? I already know what '<,'> indicates.

Comment: @PeterRincker perhaps `V%y` could be `yG`? save another one.  I didn't test though. :)

Comment: @ramonovski, `'[` and `']` are automatic marks created by Vim at the beginning and end of the text you just pasted.

Comment: @kent, you are right using `yG` would take off a stroke. Of course that means it has to be at the end of the file. You could take off another stroke by doing changing the range on `:norm` to `,$`. So a total of 19: `qqyG%p:,$norm ^Q^A%q`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Enter visual mode and select the lines to be included in the macro execution an type:

```
:normal @n
```

Then, when you hit enter, the macro will be applied to selected lines

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try:

```
qqv%:s/\d\+/\=submatch(0)+1/^M[[yGGp
```

short explanation

```
qq                              "recording to register q
v%                              "select things between { and }
:s/\d\+/\=submatch(0)+1/^M      "just do +1 to all numbers (selected range)
[[                              "back to begin {
yG                              "yank till the end
Gp                              "paste at the end
```

then do `150@q`

if you record the same macro, type `^M` simply by `Enter`

if you assign the macro to `@q` type `^M` by `<c-v><enter>`

btw, this won't win golf, since the function name `submatch(0)` is too long...:)

Comment: Thank you, Kent, your solution worked too and I learned about the submatch() function.

Answer (score 0):

With my [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355), once you have yanked the original block into a register, you can paste `[N]` auto-incremented blocks simply with `[N]gPp` (*paste linewise with all numbers incremented*).

The plugin also allows several other manipulations of the way the text is pasted.